# How to Enable CORS from Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, preflight

I am using react to send data to my API. Every POST request I make gives me an OPTIONS request, and I need to fix this. I think I might need to do some preflight structure but after reading about it I still do not know how to implement it.

At the moment I am connecting to my API as so...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode:'cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
    });
```

This is called `onSubmit`. I am sending some data to my POST request so I am assuming I need those headers.

Now in my node js server API I have the following handler...

```
var responseHeaders = {  
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    "access-control-allow-headers": "content-type, accept",
    "access-control-max-age": 10,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
        res.writeHead(statusCode, responseHeaders);
        res.end();
    }
    console.log("hello");
   ...
```

This does not work however, when I make a request I get...

```
OPTIONS /login 200 8.570 ms - 4
```

If I remove the headers the POST works but the data (username, password) is not passed through.

How can I bypass this OPTIONS problem?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7067966/3284355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.post` is as the name implies, for `POST` requests. `OPTIONS` request won't get routed to that method.

You need to write a handler specific for [options](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD) like so,

```
app.options("*",function(req,res,next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get("Origin")||"*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   //other headers here
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: ok this catches the options request, but the POST request is still not being read, and I kinda need it to pass data.

Comment: no Errors, the options request above seems to work. But then my POST handler which comes after OPTIONS handler does not work

Answer (score 3):

The browser sends a preflight Options requests to the server to check if CORS is enabled on the server. To enable cors on the server side add this to your server code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });
```