# Axios always fails for some reason

Tags: reactjs

```
      handleLoginClick(event) {

        var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/";
        var self = this;
        var payload={
            "email": "myusername",//this.state.username,
            "password": "mypassword"//this.state.password
        };
        axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                alert('success')
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert('NO') .  // <----- always reaches here.
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

For some reason, this code always fails and alert 'NO'. the endpoint I'm trying is valid, and accessible with those parameters from curl. Any ideas what's wrong?

I do have:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Console output:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: What is the console error that it gives

Comment: edited post to reflect

Comment: API request from Browser need to be valided with Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, you need to supply these headers from you API

Comment: If you are using a NODEJS API see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990550/how-to-fix-options-request-in-node-js/39990970#39990970

Comment: I'm using Python/Django as my API provider. Looking into providing this. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah check it, It will solve your issue

Comment: Try out [this Django app](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requests are not readable by the JavaScript due to [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). In order to allow cross-domain requests, you must enable [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) headers server-side.
For development purposes, you may use a proxy (own, or [a simple service like crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/)) or the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

To allow calls from any domain you must serve the following header (`*` - means any, however, you can list domains here):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

To enable CORS in Django app please see [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) or [django-cors-middleware](https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware).