# Not getting request body when using Fetch API but JQuery AJAX works.

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I am working on a project where

1. My APIs are written in Express.js (4.16)- in PORT: 1337
2. Front end app is in React.js (16.2) - in PORT: 3000

So there are several APIs i need to call from React.js app, the problem am facing is:

### PROBLEM IS -

**DOESN'T WORK  at all- [fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)**

```
fetch('localhost:1337/rest/api', {
    body: JSON.stringify( {name: "Sidd", "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor .."} ),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'post'
})
```

When am using [fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), I am not getting the request body in my API defined in Express.js

```
console.log(req.body) // On logging the request body
{} // am getting this [empty]
```

---

**WORKS- jQuery AJAX**

```
$.ajax('localhost:1337/rest/api', {
    type: 'post',
    data: {name: "Sidd", "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor .."},  
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log('Error' + errorMessage);
    }
});
```

However am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` ERROR!

But at least am **GETTING** the request body in my API in this case. Also tested my APIs through POSTMAN and they work totally fine.
I have seen all the discussions out there online but nothing works.

Oh! I would also like to add this - In my Express.js setup am using body-parser properly

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '2mb'}));                           // 2mb file upload limit
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '2mb', extended: true}));     // 2mb file upload limit
```

### WHAT I WANT!

1. Solution for fetch() API
2. If NOT fetch() API, how to remove the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error from my jQuery Ajax call.
3. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-enable-cors-from-nodejs-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990550/how-to-enable-cors-from-nodejs-server/39990970#39990970)

Answer (score 2):

Since `1337` and `3000` are the different ports, so you are encountering [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request.

First, set `mode: cors` in fetch request, and then add a router handler

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('access-control-allow-origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1728000)
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.json({ status: 0, message: '', payload: null })
  }
  next()
})
```

before your `rest/api` handler.

After doing that, you are good to go.

Comment: Well it will solve the cors prob +1 for that, but what bout the [fetch API]? Any clue?

Comment: You can read the [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) documentation for more details. And if you are confused about the `mode` property, please check out [Request()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request)

Comment: Your answer helped me to realise I need to allow Credentials on my CORS related settings in a Django app. So thanks for this.